# C code Count elements in array that are not null

Tags: c, arrays, count, element

going over old exam papers and doing questions, for this one:

array is:

```
char* s[]={"one","two",NULL,NULL,"five","",""};
```

using function name:

```
int inUse(char *s[],int len)
```

I have to determine the number of elements that are not NULL.

I have come up with:

```
int count=0;

for(i=0; i<7, i++)
{
    if(s !=NULL)
    {
        count ++;
    }
}
```

Is this correct? thankyou

REVISED:

```
int inUse(char *s[],int len)
{

    int count=0;

    for(i=0; i<len, i++)
    {
        if(s[i] != NULL)
        {
            count ++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: `char s*[]={"one","two",NULL,NULL,five,"",""};` doesn't compile. Did you mean `char* s[]={"one","two",NULL,NULL,five,"",""};`? That won't compile too, unless `five` is a `char` array declared somewhere. And how do you call your function? And no, that isn't right.

Comment: `s` never changes based on the value of `i`, so the loop is pointless (unless of course you're missing something....)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all,

```
char s*[]={"one","two",NULL,NULL,five,"",""};
```

doesn't compile. Did you mean

```
char* s[]={"one","two",NULL,NULL,"five","",""};
```

Secondly, I assume you call your function using

```
inUse(s, 7);

/* OR */

inUse(s, sizeof(s) / sizeof(*s));
```

Thirdly, you should change

```
if(s !=NULL)
```

to

```
if(s[i] != NULL)
```

since you want to check if individual elements of the array are not `NULL`.

Lastly, I assume that you return `count` from the function.

Comment: i copied the question from the exam paper so im assuming here the lecturer made a mistake there lol.

but your reply has cleared things up for me thanks mate, forgot some really simple things there! ><

Comment: Did you mean `int inUse(char *s[],int len)` instead of `int inUse(s,7)`? And you should use `for(i=0; i<len, i++)` because you pass `len` to the function.

Comment: i cant wait for the day when programming becomes unconsciously easy as driving a manual car lol